# Google Ads API Discovery Ads & Universal App Campaign type

Tags: .net, google-ads-api

I am writing a .NET script and I am using Google Ads API v3.

How to check in Google Ads API if a campaign is of type Discovery Ads or Universal App Campaign type?
What segment or dimension to use for these two specific types because I can't seem to find anything on the internet.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Discovery campaigns** are **not** currently supported in Google Ads API. For a list of campaign types that are supported, you can refer to [this](https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/docs/campaigns/overview#campaign_types) guide.

To check if a campaign is of type **Universal App Campaign**, you can use GetCampaigns() to pull campaigns where the `advertising_channel_sub_type` is `"APP_CAMPAIGN"` or `"APP_CAMPAIGN_FOR_ENGAGEMENT."`

Answer (score 0):

There's a dedicated ENUM for this on the client.

```
channel=GoogleAdsClient.get_type('AdvertisingChannelTypeEnum')
```

Then to access it, for example, to output it with the usual row, pass it the value of the advertising_channel_type that comes back in the row. Make sure you ask for it in the query though (in your select clause, make sure you've got campaign.advertising_channel_type) :

```
print(channel.AdvertisingChannelType.Name(row.campaign.advertising_channel_type).title())
```